# How to customize caption for supplementary materials?

Tags: hyperref, captions, citing, ref

I have two tex files, i.e., `main.tex` and `supplementary.tex`.

**For `supplementary.tex`, I  have three requirements:**

1. Captions of figures start with prefix 'Figure S'. So I set,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure S}
\begin{document}
% some supplementary materials
\end{document}
```

2. There are no spaces between caption prefix and index. To be specific, I want to have 'Figure S1' rather than 'Figure S 1' in captions. So I set,

```
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\thefigure}
```

3. Citations of figures start with 'Supplementary Figure'. That is when we cite a figure, let's say the first figure, I want to have 'Supplementary Figure 1', here I used `\autoref` command and set

```
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Supplementary Figure}
```

When I cite a figure, I did

```
\autoref{figurelabel}
```

For this `supplementary.tex` file, all requirements are realized.

**For `main.tex`, I have two requirements:**

1. Citations of figures from supplementary also start with the prefix 'Figure S'. So I set

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\externaldocument[supp-]{supplementary} % for cite the external supplementary tex file
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Figure S}
```

When I cited figures from the supplementary in this main file,  I did

```
\autoref{supp-figurelabel}
```

However, this resulted that citations of figures belonging to `main.tex` also started with 'Figure S' rather than 'Figure'

2. Citations of figures from supplementary have no spaces between the prefix and title. I can not do this because of similar reasons as the last case.

In summary, for `supplementary.tex`, everything seems ok. But how can I realize my requirements for `main.tex`?

Comment: Please clarify the nature of `supplementary.tex`. Is it an individually compilable file , i.e., does it have its own `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` statements? Or is "just" a collection of text and LaTeX macros?

Comment: @Mico I have updated it. Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, the captions of the `figure` environments in `supplementary.tex` say `Figure S1`, `Figure S2`, etc.  Second, when they're cross-referenced *from within* `supplementary.tex` the cross-referencing call-outs are supposed to say `Supplementary Figure 1`, `Suplementary Figure 2, i.e., *without* the `S` prefix. Third, when they're cross-referenced from within `main.tex`, the call-outs are supposed say `Figure S1`, `Figure S2`, etc. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: @Mico Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks. What readers of `supplementary.pdf` will probably find confusing (and maybe even bizarre) is that the *captions* of the figures say `Figure S1`, `Figure S2`, etc., yet *cross-referencing call-outs* to these figures, prpduced by `\autoref` or `\cref`, say `Supplementary Figure 1`, `Supplementary Figure 2`, etc. What's the purpose of this discrepancy? If the cross-referencing call-outs to the supplementary figures could be set to say `Figure S1`, `Figure S2`, etc in both `main.pdf` and `supplementary.pdf`, the formatting task would be much simpler -- *and* readers might be less confused.

Comment: @Mico Actually `Supplementary Figure 1` is the title of a section. I had multiple figures in supplementary materials. For each figure, I put it into a section with title like `Supplementary Figure X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying the structure of `supplementary.tex` and for noting that `Supplementary Figure 1`, `Supplementary Figure 2`, etc will occur in section headers, not in "ordinary" cross-referencing call-outs.

Since the cross-referencing needs in `supplementary.tex` are very narrowly defined, I believe it makes sense to set up an extra counter variable and to increment it (via `\refstepcounter`) after each `\caption` statement, and to associate a separate `\label` with each value of the extra counter. As the following code shows, this is fairly easy to implement and, very importantly, doesn't interfere in any way with the usual `\label`, `\autoref`, and `\cref` measures.

Here, then, is how I would set up `supplementary.tex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\renewcommand\thefigure{S\arabic{figure}} % modify \thefigure, *not* \figurename
\newcounter{myfig} % create an extra counter variable

\begin{document}

\section*{Supplementary Figure \ref*{myfig:a}}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{A supplementary figure}
\label{fig:a} 
\refstepcounter{myfig}\label{myfig:a} % <-- increment and \label the extra counter
\end{figure}

\section*{Supplementary Figure \ref*{myfig:b}}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Another supplementary figure}
\label{fig:b} 
\refstepcounter{myfig}\label{myfig:b} % <-- increment and \label the extra counter
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you wanted to cross-reference the figures with `\cref` calls, you can certainly do so.

---

And here's how I would structure `main.tex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\externaldocument[supp-]{supplementary} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cref{fig:1}, \cref{supp-fig:a,supp-fig:b}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{A main figure}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!